# TableLayout - TextView and ImageView inline

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have built an app that dynamically adds TextViews and ImageViews into the TableLayout. I am facing one small issue, I can't get ImageView to be displayed inline with TextView fields. In my fragment  I get the results back from a server and display it in the layout.

I have tried several ways such as setting the gravity of TextView to Center vertical like this
I tried limiting the width of the text fields but it won't work.

```
    firstRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

This is how my rows are populated:

```
    businessNameRow.addView(businessNameField);
```

I am adding sets dynamically, each set consists of 7 TextView rows and 1 ImageView in each row as follows:

```
TableRow firstRow = new TableRow(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
TableRow secondRow = new TableRow(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
TableRow thirdRow = new TableRow(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
TableRow fourthRow = new TableRow(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
TableRow fifthRow = new TableRow(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
TableRow sixthRow = new TableRow(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
TableRow imageRow = new TableRow(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
TableRow seventhRow = new TableRow(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

Then I just add the row to the table

```
final TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.tableResultsGPS);

tl.addView(firstRow); //And so on
```

My TableLayout is placed within ScrollView so I can scroll through list of results.

Attaching image of what I want to achieve and what it looks like now. 
[image]

Comment: can you show an image of what you are getting now

Comment: Attached it to the main post. This is what I'm getting.

Comment: Can you share the code where you set the layout rules for the image and the text in each row?

Comment: do consider my answer, i think its much easier to achieve with that and it offers much more flexibility

Comment: In the XML file? Because I removed all the layout params to keep the code clean as I couldn't figure out what to do.

Comment: will be good if you can use an @sihao to notify me, i will receive a notification on your update

Comment: you have a look at the list view tutorial in my answer. From there, try to picture your solution in a ListView form. Try to relate it. Let me know if you are still stuck

Comment: @sihao I'm currently working on the solution using your way, will keep you updated. Thank you

Comment: thats great! listview is really useful for many applications too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like what you are trying to achieve is more suitable with a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) implementation.

**The general idea:**

- Create a list item with the layout of an individual item (your textview and image)
- Create a new class that models your each item
- Using a list view, bind the data to the ListView.

There are many tutorials out there. [Try this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Side Note: Good suggestion for layout choice would be relative layout for your ListView item. One of my personal favorite because of its flexiblity.